# Pushing Objects into my state array - Nextjs/React/Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, next.js, use-state

I have fetched from 2 APIs that return 2 objects. I have then put them in 2 different states (1 in each state). I want my third state to be **an array that contains BOTH of the objects**. So essentially it would be an array of objects. How would I accomplish that. When I do the below, my second object just overwrites the first, it does not push into the array. What am I missing?

```
    export default function useFetchNaveNarCatagoriesThatAreNotGenres() {
      const [trending, setTrending] = useState();
      const [toprated, setToprated] = useState();
      const [trendingandtopratedcombined, setTrendingandtopratedcombined] =
        useState([]);
    
         useEffect(() => {
            async function APIfetch() {
              const response = await fetch(
                `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/all/day?api_key=f70b3ca617a5d8978429e375c55a4fa2`
              );
              const fetchedtrending = await response.json();
              setTrending(fetchedtrending);
              setTrendingandtopratedcombined(fetchedtrending)
              console.log(
                "This is me testing my fetch trending",
                fetchedtrending
              );
            }
            APIfetch();
        
          }, []);    
        
          useEffect(() => {
            async function APIfetch() {
              const response = await fetch(
                `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?api_key=f70b3ca617a5d8978429e375c55a4fa2&language=en-US&page=1`
              );
              const fetchedtoprated = await response.json();
              console.log(
                "This is me testing my fetch toprated",
                fetchedtoprated
              );
              setToprated(fetchedtoprated);
              setTrendingandtopratedcombined[...trendingandtopratedcombined, fetchedtoprated]);
        
            }
            APIfetch();
          }, []);

  console.log("Testing my Final", trendingandtopratedcombined)
```

Answer (score 0):

After setting both states, create useEffect and inside that you can set those values using `setTrendingandtopratedcombined` and give `[trending, toprated]` as dependencies. I think you can try something like this.

Comment: Can you explain why I need the dependencies of [trending, toprated] in my useEffect. If I list my useEffect's in the right order, should not that be enough to ensure that I am adding both states to the setTrendingandtopratedcombined? If they all do not have dependencies thus execute on mount would it not then default to the order in the code?

Comment: You suggestion does not work or was not clear enough, do you mind providing a code snippet of what you are trying to say?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).